# How to test a Node app on a Windows system provisioned on the Cloud

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10, cloud, windows-11

I have a node app which I develop and test on a Mac.

I would like to test it on a Windows10 or Windows11 without having to buy a Windows PC, so I am wondering if there is an easy way to get a Windows system on the Cloud and which would be the easiest way.

Comment: I'm not clear about how you want to test. Do you just need to run unit tests on Windows, or do you want to install the app and let it run? Is this a backend or frontend application or both? Do you need access to a browser, or to a remote desktop? I'm afraid this question is a bit too vague as it is currently formulated.

Comment: You are right, the question is vague. I will post a new more precise question. Thanks